# Facebook Comment Plugin not Loading for Github Page

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages, facebook-comments, facebooktoolkit

I have a blog in GitHub-Pages, where I want to load Facebook Comment Plugin: 
https://juspreet51.github.io/blog_posts/demo.html

From the Facebook Comment Plugin [Doscumentaion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments), I used following parameters:-

- URL to comment on: https://juspreet51.github.io/blog_posts/demo.html
- Number of Posts: 5
- Then I clicked on Get-Code button

And then used generated code in following .html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- facebook plugin JavaScript SDK -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v8.0" nonce="uOgIM47N"></script>

  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <h3>Below this line, ideally comment should appear</h3>

  <!-- comments to appear below -->
  <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://juspreet51.github.io/blog_posts/demo.html" data-numposts="10" data-width=""></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Still, the comment plugin is not loading, can you please point what might have gone wrong?

*Comment section is visible when I visit [the link](https://juspreet51.github.io/blog_posts/demo.html) from mobile phone browser 
So I tried clearing my PC browser history and cache, still comment section is not visible in the PC browser, but visible just mobile browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to request permission to do that.

Facebook comment on the page when u generate the code :

[image]

So make sure u click on that link on the notification and grab your permission for a public access

Comment: where did you took this screenshot from? As I can't find this in the official documentation page that I listed in the question

Comment: click on get code button : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the console of the website in your browser which you are facing the issue and check whether your browser is blocking the cookies

error may look like this:

```
            A cookie associated with the cross-site resource at https://facebook.com/ was set without the `samesite` attribute. It has been blocked
```